# Convert a text file to xml using scripting

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a text output file. In that file I have a user name list. I need to convert this text file to xml please help me to do this.

```
Mytest.txt
----------

Pain
paeen
kholi
sachin
deve
head
```

I need a xml syntax for these all users

```
<start>
    <username> Pain </username>
</end>
```

Something like this. I have 1000+ users in this list. Please guide me what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <start>
<username> Pain </username>
</end>

Comment: ok, post the final result for your current 6 users

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

With this sed command you can have your result (I used `</start>` to end `<start>` xml tag in order for the XML to be well formed):

```
$ sed -n "s:.*:<start><username>&</username></start>:p" Mytest.txt
<start><username>Pain</username></start>
<start><username>paeen</username></start>
<start><username>kholi</username></start>
<start><username>sachin</username></start>
<start><username>deve</username></start>
<start><username>head</username></start>
```